# Batchfile to convert AVI to MKV and tag first audio and first video file as English language

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, language, matroska

I have a bunch of *.avi videos in a folder on my Windows computer that I would like to convert (or remux) to *.mkv. Since I have a lot of files I would like to automate this process with a batch script using mkvmerge.

I simply need a batch file that can remux from avi to mkv and mark the language to that it shows up correctly at playpack.

How can I achieve this using only a batch file and mkvmerge?

I found this as an answer to a similar question. It does the AVI>MTK part nicely

```
for %%A IN (*.flv) do ( mkvmerge.exe -o "remux-%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A") pause
```

PS pre-thx to arate as I stole most of his wording and changed it appropriately

This is what I came up with works OK
for %%A IN (*.AVI) do ( "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~nA [SD WS DVD XviD MP3-2.0].mkv" --language 0:eng --language 1:eng "%%~A")

Comment: What is the question?